# VBSの正規表現(改行あり)で,検索文字列の次の行を取り出す方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: 正規表現, vbs

(参考)指定された文字列を正規表現で検索します。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc392389.aspx

```
Function RegExpTest(patrn, strng)
    Dim regEx, Match, Matches          ' 変数を作成します。
    Set regEx = New RegExp             ' 正規表現を作成します。
    regEx.Pattern = patrn              ' パターンを設定します。
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True            ' 大文字と小文字を区別しないように設定します。
    regEx.Global = True                ' 文字列全体を検索するように設定します。
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(strng) ' 検索を実行します。
    For Each Match in Matches          ' Matches コレクションに対して繰り返し処理を行います。
        RetStr = RetStr & "一致する文字列が見つかった位置は、"
        RetStr = RetStr & Match.FirstIndex & " です。一致した文字列は、"
        RetStr = RetStr & Match.Value & " です。" & vbCRLF
    Next
    RegExpTest = RetStr
End Function
'      012    34        567    89        012    34        567    89        0    12 
mySTR="IS1" & vbCrLf & "is2" & vbCrLf & "IS3" & vbCrLf & "is4" & vbCrLf & "5" & vbCrLf
msgbox(mySTR)
msgbox(len(mySTR))
MsgBox(RegExpTest("is.", mySTR))
'????5を取り出す「改行の正規表現」の方法を教えて下さい。??????????????????????????????????????
MsgBox(RegExpTest("is."& vbCrLf, mySTR))
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'IS1
'is2
'IS3
'is4
'5
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'23
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'一致する文字列が見つかった位置は、0 です。一致した文字列は、IS1 です。
'一致する文字列が見つかった位置は、5 です。一致した文字列は、is2 です。
'一致する文字列が見つかった位置は、10 です。一致した文字列は、IS3 です。
'一致する文字列が見つかった位置は、15 です。一致した文字列は、is4 です。
```

①上記の関数は、改行に対応していますか？
②splitを使う方法しかありませんか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

> 検索文字列の次の行を取り出す方法を教えて下さい。

`Match.FirstIndex`、`Match.Value`を使われているようですが[`Match.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc392435.aspx)もあります。
`Match.FirstIndex + Match.Length`が検索文字列の次の**文字**を指します。検索している正規表現パターンが`"is."& vbCrLf`と改行で終わっているため、実質的に次の**行**を指すことになります。